# Indentify wrong request type for Python Flask RestApi

Tags: python, flask

I have a RestApi developed in python using flask, the Api only supports HTTP request with Json format, so now I would like to identify unsupported request type in Python code. 
I was trying to use

```
from flask import request
```

but how to check if its not a HTTP Json request? Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be great if you could show that you have made a good effort to solve it yourself. Try editing your question to add the code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Usually the content type is declared in the request header. So using the request, you can check if such a header is present. For example:

```
@app.route('/',methods = ['POST'])
def add():
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json; charset=UTF-8':
        print (request.get_json())
        return "json OK"
    raise FailedRequest
```